# pandas: sample groups after groupby

Tags: python, pandas

How can I sample groups after a groupby in pandas? Say I want to get the first half of groups after groupby.

```
In [194]: df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['john', 'george', 'john','andrew','Daniel','george','andrew','Daniel'], 'hits':[12,34,13,23,53,47,20,48]})
In [196]: grouped = df.groupby('name')
```

There are 'john', 'george', 'andrew', 'daniel' 4 groups in *grouped* and I'm interested in getting 2 groups out of the 4. It doesn't matter which 2 groups it returns.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You can sample the names ahead of time and only group the chosen names:

```
selected_names = np.random.choice(df.name.unique(),2,replace = False)
grouped = df[df.name.isin(selected_names)].groupby('name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick replies, ajcr and cwharland. I was probably not clear about what I want, but your suggestions are great. I did:

```
choices =np.random.choice(grouped.indices.keys(), 2, replace=False)
df[df['name'].isin(choices)]
```

and get the results I hoped:

```
Out[215]: 
   hits    name
0    12    john
2    13    john
3    23  andrew
6    20  andrew
```

Thank you both!

Comment: there's no need for a `groupby` if that is your desired output.  Simply do: `selected_names = np.random.choice(df.name.unique(),2,replace = False)` followed by `df[df.name.isin(selected_names)]`