# pandas, keep groupby groups after apply

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

I would like to use `groupby` on my dataframe and then chain a series of function calls on each group with `apply`.

As a first prototype, I've set up an example where I convert the entries of my dataframe from string to numeric. The dataframe looks like this:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame({
    "number": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"], 
    "type": ["a",] * 4 + ["b",] * 4})
```

The resulting dataframe is:

[image: structure of the dataframe]

The numbers in this dataframe are strings. So before I can use any math operations, they have to be converted to a numerical type. That's what I would like to do with apply:

```
frame.groupby("type")["number"].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

But the result is a single series which contains all items:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
6    7
7    8
Name: number, dtype: int64
```

I've read the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) for this. Apparently you can use `transform` or `apply`.
In the samples, the grouped structure seems to be kept.

Maybe it is something related to `pd.to_numeric` ? So I tried:

```
frame.groupby("type")["number"].apply(lambda x: int(x))
```

Which results in a TypeError:

> TypeError: cannot convert the series to

Apparently the apply gets a whole group as parameter.
The results for each group seem to be concatenated into one dataframe.

Is it possible to use apply in a way that keeps the grouped structure ?
I would like a call that applies the function to each column within the groups and keeps the groups. Then I could chain the calls.

A related question I've found is this:
[pandas: sample groups after groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27304538/pandas-sample-groups-after-groupby)

But the answer suggests to apply the function before the grouping. Which doesn't work well with chaining the functions. And not at all for something like `mean()`.

Comment: Why don't you do `df['number'] = df['number'].astype(int)` *first*, and they do your groupby?

Comment: The setup is just an example. This tip is basically the same as the answer on sampling after groupby: applying the necessary functions first.
It's definitely a good answer for this specific problem, but I would like to know how to do the chaining for more complex cases

Comment: I don't understand your title. What do you mean keep group structure? """Is it possible to use apply in a way that keeps the grouped structure ? I would like a call that applies the function to each column within the groups and keeps the groups. Then I could chain the calls.""" <- what's these means? can you use more examples to illustrate? What's the `grouped structure` you want to keep? Are you trying to say you want to keep the number of rows the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages and behaviors you are getting here are because you are in fact calling :
`pd.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)` and not `Series.apply` or `DataFrame.apply`.

> But the result is a single series which contains all items:

It seems to correspond with case #3 described [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html).

> Apparently the apply gets a whole group as parameter.

Yes

> The results for each group seem to be concatenated into one dataframe.

Depends on the case linked above

> Is it possible to use apply in a way that keeps the grouped structure ? I would like a call that applies the function to each column within the groups and keeps the groups. Then I could chain the calls.

You would have to give more details on what you are trying to achieve but `aggregate` or `transform` seem good candidates indeed