# pandas: groupby two columns and get random selection of groups such that each value in the first column will be represented by a single group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

It's similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50004641/select-sample-random-groups-after-groupby-in-pandas), but with an additional level of complexity.
In my case, I have a the following *dataframe*:

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list('aaabbbabababbaaa'), 'col2': list('cdddccdsssssddcd'), 'val': range(0, 16)})
```

output:

```
   col1 col2  val
0     a    c    0
1     a    d    1
2     a    d    2
3     b    d    3
4     b    c    4
5     b    c    5
6     a    d    6
7     b    s    7
8     a    s    8
9     b    s    9
10    a    s   10
11    b    s   11
12    b    d   12
13    a    d   13
14    a    c   14
15    a    d   15
```

My goal is to select random groups of `groupby(['col1', 'col2'])` such that each value of `col1` will be selected only once.
This can be executed by the following code:

```
g = df.groupby('col1')
indexes = []
for _, group in g:
    g_ = group.groupby('col2')
    a = np.arange(g_.ngroups)
    np.random.shuffle(a)
    indexes.extend(group[g_.ngroup().isin(a[:1])].index.tolist())
```

output:

```
print(df[df.index.isin(indexes)])
   col1 col2  val
4     b    c    4
5     b    c    5
8     a    s    8
10    a    s   10
```

However, I'm looking for a more concise and pythonic way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to sufffle your two columns with `sample` and `drop_duplicates` by col1, so that you keep only one couple per col1 value. then `merge` the result to df to select all the rows with these couples.

```
print(df.merge(df[['col1','col2']].sample(frac=1).drop_duplicates('col1')))
  col1 col2  val
0    b    s    7
1    b    s    9
2    b    s   11
3    a    s    8
4    a    s   10​
```

or with `groupby` and `sample` a bit the same idea but to select only one row per col1 value with `merge` after

```
df.merge(df[['col1','col2']].groupby('col1').sample(n=1))
```

EDIT: to get both the selected rows and the others rows, then you can use the parameter indicator in the merge and do a left merge. then `query` each separately:

```
m = df.merge(df[['col1','col2']].groupby('col1').sample(1), how='left', indicator=True)
print(m)
select_ = m.query('_merge=="both"')[df.columns]
print(select_)
comp_ = m.query('_merge=="left_only"')[df.columns]
print(comp_)
```

Comment: Why do you need `sample(frac=1)`? I think `df.merge(df[['col1','col2']].drop_duplicates('col1'))` will also work

Comment: @itamarkanter using `frac=1` shuffle all the rows, because in the first case, the condition about keeping only one row per value in col1 is done after with drop_duplicates, so you need to shuffle all the rows. whle in the second method, as you already say you want to groupby col1, then you can keep only one row per col1 value

Comment: I like the use of `df.merge`.  original thinking!

Comment: @itamarkanter `df.merge(df[['col1','col2']].drop_duplicates('col1'))` this will work to select only one group per value of col1, but it is not random choice as you will keep always the first row of each value in col1

Comment: I didn't mention this in the question but actually, I'm also interested in the complementary _dataframe_, any idea how can I do it?